# How To Move SharePoint App From Development Site To Production Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-web-part, azure, visual-studio-2015

I have created a SharePoint app in SharePoint online in visual studio. This consists of a client web part and a web app hosted in Azure. I have set up a development site and successfully managed to get the app to run. it's just basic at this point because I am more interested in determining how to get it into sharepoint.

[image]

But now I am trying to get that app into another site I am having major hurdles. Here are the steps I have taken.

1. I have deployed the web project. I am assuming this is successful since it shows the changes I make in the development site. I can't imagine that any settings need to be changed for deployment to another site since this deploys to the web app in Azure (I think)?

[image]

[image]

2. So the next step I do is Package the App to send to sharepoint online. The potential problems here are that I use the same ClientID and Client Secret I used for my development site. From what I have read this should be handled in the packaging process and no changes need to be made as I try to push the app into the new site. So I am assuming the clientID is not site specific?

[image]

3. So once I have that as a .app file I go to the newly created AppCatalog Site and upload the file.

[image]

Once uploaded I can see it in the product ID list as below.

[image]

4. Then I go to our test site and try to pull the app. As you can see it has a message under the app 'You can't add this app here'.

[image]

When I click on 'find out why' I get the below message.

[image]

I have been unable to find an answer on the web that explains what to do. It's very frustrating and have spent about 8 hours trying to figure this out. I'm sure it's some setting somewhere that needs changing, but don't know what that setting is. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to go ahead an answer this to save some poor soul in the future. The problem was with the App Manifest file. I had the Permissions => Scope set to Site Collection. This needs to be changed to 'Web'.